# How to remove \n\r or [] in stdout.readlines() in paramiko python

Tags: python, paramiko

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(f'vol create {vol} -aggregate {aggregate} -size {size}')
print("The output is: ")
print(stdout.readlines())

print("The error is: ")
print(stderr.readlines())
```

Output:

The output is:

```
['\r\r\n', 'Last login time: 9/11/2020 13:54:24\r\r\n', '\x\r\n', 'Error: command failed: Duplicate volume name vol.\r\n', '\r\n']
```

The error is:

```
[]
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you print each line of the list:

```
lines = stdout.readlines()
for l in lines:
   print(l)
```

Or, alternatively, join the list and print it:

```
print(''.join(stdout.readlines()))
```